# SQL Profiler for Mac OS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, profiler

Is there a SQL profiler MSSSQL that can be installed and run on Mac? It doesn't matter if it is a paid version as long as it can run on my Mac OS. Thanks.

Comment: Do you just need a sql client? Have you tried sqlops?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/download

Comment: What version of sql are you trying to trace? Why do you specifically need profiler? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My version is MSSQL Server 2016 13.0.2164. I am trying to trace the database error process on my stored procedure.

Comment: My initial reaction is that profiler is the wrong tool for this job. Profiler is useful to identify unexpected traffic, connections and load on a server. It helps you see what is occurring when you aren't sure whats happening in what order at the time. You should be able to debug a Stored procedure using normal client tools. What problem do you have and what errors are you getting? Start with the basics, does the login executing the SP have sufficient privileges? and does it have the requisites privileges to carry out each of the tasks within the SP?

Comment: Thanks Peter, I know how to debug a stored procedure what I am aiming with the profiler is to be able to trace what SP is causing a certain problem when the basics is not enough to identify the problem. Anyway, I have already followed Brent's suggestion of using VM as I would using microsoft SSMS anyway. Brent's is correct we have website's like to share knowledge to people who are seeking for it and leveling our answer with their knowledge is the way to go. ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but here's a few options:

**Run a [server-side trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx).** You don't get the Profiler GUI, but the good news is that this kind of tracing is faster. (Heck, I recommend this to folks even when they have Windows on the desktop.) SQL Server Central has a [good Stairway to Server-side Tracing](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72363/). Server-side traces can output to file or to table - I'd caution against writing the trace data into a table on the same server that you're monitoring because that'll have a performance impact.

**Run Profiler in a VM.** After all, if you're managing SQL Server, you probably need SQL Server Management Studio anyway, and that's still Windows-only. (That's how I manage SQL Server personally - I'm a Microsoft Certified Master of SQL Server, and I've been using Macs since the mid-2000s.)

**Run [sp_BlitzCache](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/).** The open source sp_BlitzCache analyzes the most resource-intensive queries in your plan cache - without starting a heavy-overhead trace or XE session. SQL Server is already gathering this data for you on every supported version/edition. Yes, right now, even as you're reading advice on a web site. You can run it from anything app runs T-SQL, like Microsoft's new cross-platform [SQL Operations Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/what-is). (Disclaimer: I'm one of the sp_BlitzCache authors.)

**Use Extended Events instead.** (This isn't really a solution, but I know someone's going to suggest it, so might as well get it out of the way. The Extended Events people are like vegans, crossfitters, and atheists: they can't wait to tell you about their religion.) Extended Events is the replacement for Profiler, but the thing is, if you're just getting started, you're going to want to use SSMS's excellent wizard for setting up a new XE session - meaning, you still need SSMS. There's also a ["Profiler" extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=sql-server-2017) for [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download?view=sql-server-2017), but...that's actually Extended Events.

**Get a third party monitoring tool.** If you need to know what's happening on your SQL Server on a regular basis, this is usually more lightweight than running Profiler. Plus, they have way more smarts built in to tell you what's been happening.

Comment: An Extended Events trace is a viable solution since it can be created with DDL on macOS using [SOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/what-is) and viewed by using 'sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file' from a query window. I think a GUI XE trace create/view would be a nice feature to suggest for SOS.

Comment: Wow, your answer is amazing, Brent. Can I call you amazing Brent? It is full of needed information with an extra wittiness (made me laugh).  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I will go with the VM. What VM can you suggest me using Brent?

Comment: @SandyPabilonia hahaha, thanks. You can use VMware Fusion or Parallels or VirtualBox.

Comment: @DanGuzman as I wrote in the answer, XE isn't a viable solution when someone's asking a question like this. You gotta know who you're working with on the other side - if they're asking this question, they're not a good fit for crafting XE sessions by hand, and figuring out how to read them by hand. They're not quite at your experience level. ;-)

Comment: @BrentOzar, I hear you. The SQL Server Windows tools are more mature at this point so a VM on maxOS makes tracing easier. But I still suggest the OP avoid using the deprecated Profiler and consider becoming familiar with the cross platform SOS tool for routine tasks like queries like object browsing since that avoids firing up a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure Data Studio runs on mac, and has a Sql Profiler plugin available for free, installable from within the app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/azure-data-studio/

Comment: It's not Profiler - it uses Extended Events. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=sql-server-2017